# What is the best approach upgrading from .NET 2 to 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-2.0

We've been developing apps since .NET 2 release and now we are planning to upgrade to .NET 3.5. What is the best approach upgrading from .NET 2.0 to 3.5?

BTW ... the external components that we use are:
1. EntitySpace - ORM
2. Microsoft Enterprise Library
3. Microsoft ReportingViewer 9.00
4. Telerik ASP.NET Controls

Comment: It will be so easy that you're going to wonder why you didn't do it sooner.

Comment: Are you also upgrading from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: @Michael: Now we have VS since 2009 BUT just one app that we need to upgrade to .NET 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET Framework 3.5 is a superset of .NET Framework 2.0. You shouldn't have to do anything except re-target your build output. If any third party components require .NET 2.0 then it will have to still be installed on the target machine.

Comment: Just to clarify this, eventhough the third party is built for .NET 2 ... I am still be able to use this?!?!

Answer (score 4):

.NET 2.0 and 3.5 Share the same version of CLR (2.0). What .NET framework 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 with a bunch of added lib for WCF, WPF, Linq ....

you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the upgrade is pretty much trivial, *but* you may have to change *some* code, because some library methods may have been deprecated. (Well, you won't *have* to, you'll just get warnings about it.)